# How do I read x amount from a buffer

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, tcpclient, tcplistener

**For the sake of this question, let's assume nothing is wrong with the server and let's just focus on the client and how it receives the data.**

So I have this client / server setup going and this is how it currently flows.
The server sends a packet that's 5000 bytes.
All the packets are structured like this.. The first 4 bytes are reserved for the length of the entire packet, the next byte is reserved for the OpCode.. The remaining bytes represents the actual payload.

`Length (4 bytes) | OpCode (1 byte) | Payload (x bytes)`

On the client I'm currently doing this

```
byte[] RawBuffer = new byte[Constants.BufferSize]; //Constants.BufferSize = 1024
int packLen = 0;
int totalReceived = 0;
private byte[] allData;


private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    var stream = (NetworkStream)ar.AsyncState;
    var received = stream.EndRead(ar);
    Debug.Print($"Data received: {received} bytes");

    //If we haven't assigned a length yet
    if (packLen <= 0)
    {
        //Use "allData" as the final buffer that we use to process later down the line.
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(RawBuffer))
        using (var reader = new BinaryReader(ms))
        {
            packLen = reader.ReadInt32();
            allData = new byte[packLen];
        }
    }

    Buffer.BlockCopy(RawBuffer, 0, allData, 0, received);
    totalReceived += received;

    if (totalReceived == allData.Length)
    {
        Debug.Print($"We've successfully appended {allData.Length} bytes out of {packLen}");
    }

    stream.BeginRead(RawBuffer, 0, Constants.BufferSize, ReceiveCallback, _stream);
}
```

That only works if I send 1 packet from the server to the client, but if I send 5 packets for instance it never actually splits them up.

How do I properly split them up so that once it's received the full packet based on the `Length` header, it prints out `"Received packet successfully"`

Comment: TCP will not send/receive all the data in one chunk especially if you are send a large amount of data.  So receive end needs to know where the data ends.  You are sending ASCII data so I would add a return at the end of each line and then at receive end read until the return.

Comment: Exactly, that's why I send the data as a buffer, structured using the packet structure as shown in the question, with the packet length. That's how the receiving end knows how much data it needs in order for it to complete 1 packet.

Comment: What is allData.Length?

Comment: The length of `allData = new byte[packLen];`

Comment: Looks like you have 4 bytes at beginning of data with the length.  When server sends 5 packets does server only put the byte count at the beginning of the first packet?  Is the byte count (4 bytes) part of the packlen or 4 additional bytes?

Comment: Hi, @RileyVarga. As I can see, you need to look at your protocol. In this case, you have a Header (Len + OpCode) which is 5 bytes, and, finally, the dynamic payload. In this case, I usually work with a state machine where I first read the header, work with it, and get the size of the next read (payload). After reads the payload your program needs to begin the cycle, read the header and, after that, read the payload. 

In particular, I like to work with different callback functions to receive and handle different parts of the protocol, it could be helpful to have a maintainable program.